# Sql Query - Find Item owned by a group of people

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following tables

```
Owner Table
item_id owner_id
  A       1
  A       2
  B       1
  B       2
  B       3
```

I want to find items owned by owner 1 & 2 only i.e. item A, not Item C

What could be a query for this ?

**Edit:**
If its not obvious, the owner list will be given by user, hence the query should be able to find items of given owner list maintaining the above criteria (i.e. not hardcoded).

At present I am doing it with a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = (
      SELECT item_id FROM  item_owners WHERE owner_id in  (:ownerIds)
      GROUP BY item_id HAVING  COUNT(distinct owner_id) = :ownerCount LIMIT 1
)
```

Where `:ownerIds` and `:ownerCount` are user inputs from ORM, and `items` is my original table of item to hold other details of item

The question is: is it a correct query ? Will it fail in any scenario ? And is it efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select item_id
from owner_item
group by item_id
having sum(case when owner_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when owner_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when owner_id not in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: umm, what if the queried owner list is variable, i.e. I will input for which owners i want to find the items

Comment: @dumb_terminal . . . Then that would not be the question that the OP asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as a question, not a comment.